# c++ function calling function not working

Tags: c++, function, nested

I have 3 functions:

1. First function takes an int a and prints the that number of dots.
2. The second function takes an int b and prints that number of stars.
3. The third function takes a and b and calls the dots function and stars function. When I call it in main, it returns 0 without any output.

Each of the functions work fine on their own - why doesn't the third one work then?

EDIT: Tried initializing i=0, code still compiles with the same result. Again, both functions dots() and stars() work fine when called on their own.

```
void dots(int a){
    for(int i; i<a; i++){
        cout << ".";
    }
}
void stars(int a){
    for(int i; i<a; i++){
        cout << "*";
    }
}

//(not working):
void dotsstars(int a, int b){
    dots(a);
    stars(b);
}

int main(){
    dotsstars(5, 6);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Uninitialized automatic variables (i.e. local variables) are not implicitly initialized. Their values will be *indeterminate*. And using them in C++ leads to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instantiate your iterative i values to 0. So, the for loops becomes:

```
for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
```

Also, maybe you're program is closing too quickly before you can see the results if you're not executing it from your terminal/console.

```
 int main() {

     /* your function invoked */

     int i = 0;
     cin >> i++; // This is a not so neat way to pause your program. Do something with your value so that you don't get unused variable warning.
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You can use **getch** instead

Comment: Yeah, there are many ways...system("pause") in Visual C++ too. Thanks for adding that. You can edit if you want. I'm on mobile browser and this is pretty bad to type.

Answer (score 3):

The variable `i` at the moment has garbage value so most probably the **for loop** will always be false (i.e it won't run) 
so you need to initialize `i`

```
for(int i = 0; i < number_of_times ; i++)
```

If your console closes quickly and you are not able to see the result then add `getch();` in the end, you'll have to include the `#include <conio.h>` library

P.S i know using getch() is not a good practice and it makes the program OS dependent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the incrementer i to 0:

```
for (int i=0; i<a; i++){
```

Comment: To be clear, when you use a local variable without first assigning a value to it, the results are undefined.  This comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value was about C, but the point is valid here.

Comment: **incrementer** is a really wrong term , it should be **initialized**

Comment: Initialize the variable not the incrementer

Answer (score 0):

you are not initializing `i` that's why it is not printing. `i` is a local variable so default value for local variable will be garbage value that's why you need to initialize it first.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void dots(int a){
    for(int i=0; i<a; i++){// i is set to be 0 here
        cout << ".";
        }
    }
void stars(int a){
    for(int i=0; i<a; i++){// i is set to be 0 here
        cout << "*";
        }
    }

//(not working):
void dotsstars(int a, int b){
    dots(a);
    stars(b);
}

int main(){
    dotsstars(5, 6);

    return 0;
}
```